# Calling virtual function in a parent/inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, parent

I have the following code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class A{ 
public:
  void m1(){
    cout << "A" << endl;
  }
  virtual void m2(){
    cout << "A" << endl;
  }
  void m3(){
    cout << "A" << endl;
  }
};

class B: public A{ 
public:
  void m1(){
    cout << "B" << endl ;
  }
  virtual void m2(){
    cout << "B" << endl; 
  }
  virtual void m3(){
    cout << "B" << endl;
  }
};

int main(){
  A∗ p = new B() ;
  p−>m1() ; 
  p−>m2() ; 
  p−>m3() ;
}
```

What will each call in `main()` produce? I’m see that `A B A`, but don't know how to explain this in a detail.

Comment: `A::m1` and `A::m3` are not virtual, so the code calls `A::m1` and `A::m3`. `A::m2` is virtual, so the call goes to the overriding function, `B::m2`. Marking functions virtual in a derived class doesn't affect the virtualness in the base class.

Comment: virtual -> call the function based in the type of the object, non-virtual -> call the function based on the type of the pointer. The former is worked out at runtime, the latter at compile time.

Comment: Fixed version which compiles and demonstrates difference between virtual and regular functions: https://godbolt.org/z/7GxW6rEEE

Comment: First line of your code is broken.  C++ grammar doesn't care about newlines vs other whitespace.... except that the preprocessor *does* care.

Comment: That code will produce a memory leak in the first place. (Which looks benign when it happens in `main()`, but is really bad for code reusability.)

Comment: While experimenting with `virtual` functions, also have a look at the `override` keyword. Very useful for catching errors like in you case for m3.